# verification of mobile number through sms in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a system like Online Exchange(olx). This system require a verification from the user that the number entered by the user in ad is correct or not. for that purpose I want my system to send a message to the number given by the user with a verification code.

How can I implement this system in asp.net?

Comment: Too broad. Which part are you stuck on and what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an SMS on your own.

Rather, find a service provider in your country and contact them. Providers offer paid services that are usually exposed as web services.

Technically, your application calls a provider service over http[s] and you pass a phone number and the message body. There are usually multiple payment methods, for example you can pay for a message pack or your clients can pay on their own by first sending their message to a fixed number.